# Start app remotely on computer in c#

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

I want to start an app remotely from my PC on another pc with c# code. I want to have one c# code and on another computer that the app is there and I want to run app on it, don't want to put a c# code. How can I do it?!

Answer (score 0):

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\PsTools");
info.FileName = @"C:\PsTools\psexec.exe";
info.Arguments = @"\\" + serverName + @" -i C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe";
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(info);
```

Comment: server name should be the IP address of my computer that the app is on it and wants to run or the pc name of it?

Comment: it will be the target computer

Comment: before using the above code please install psexec tool

Comment: I use this: `info.Arguments = @"\\" + "Home-pc" + @" -i C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe"` but it says that `couldn't access Home-pc the handle is invalid`. What should I do?